# What is the best way to remove interpolation from a time series data in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, time-series, interpolation

Is there a better way to remove interpolated data from time series data in pandas data frame ?

I have a time series data in which missing values are filled with interpolation but I would like to remove interpolated data and replace then with np.nan values again.

**Input Data:**

```
Index                   Column_one     Column_two     
2017:10:03 03:44:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:45:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:46:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:47:00     13.61504936     np.nan
2017:10:03 03:48:00     13.60000038     np.nan
2017:10:03 03:49:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:50:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:51:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:52:00     np.nan          14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:53:00     np.nan          14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:54:00     14.21253681     14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:55:00     14.24253273     14.80000019
```

All the missing values are filled with interpolation

**data_interpolated = data.interpolate()**

**Interpolated Data:**

```
Index                   Column_one     Column_two     
2017:10:03 03:44:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:45:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:46:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:47:00     13.61504936     14.67500051
2017:10:03 03:48:00     13.60000038     14.70000044
2017:10:03 03:49:00     13.70208979     14.72500038
2017:10:03 03:50:00     13.80417919     14.75000032
2017:10:03 03:51:00     13.9062686      14.77500025
2017:10:03 03:52:00     14.008358       14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:53:00     14.11044741     14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:54:00     14.21253681     14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:55:00     14.24253273     14.80000019
```

Now I would like to remove the interpolated values and get the initial data set.

**Desired Output:**

```
Index                   Column_one     Column_two     
2017:10:03 03:44:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:45:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:46:00     13.61504936     14.65000057
2017:10:03 03:47:00     13.61504936     np.nan
2017:10:03 03:48:00     13.60000038     np.nan
2017:10:03 03:49:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:50:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:51:00     np.nan          np.nan
2017:10:03 03:52:00     np.nan          14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:53:00     np.nan          14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:54:00     14.21253681     14.80000019
2017:10:03 03:55:00     14.24253273     14.80000019
```

Please let me know if there is any good way to implement this in Pandas or Numpy ?

Comment: Sorry but how are the missing values filled in the first place? Could you not fill them in the first place is my question. Getting back to the original df is a non-trivial issue without a copy of the original df, how can you tell if the data is legitimately increasing in a linear fashion rather than being interpolated?

Comment: @EdChum missing values are filled by linear interpolation technique, so all the filled values are linearly increasing fashion. The data I am getting is actually interpolated data and I would like to get the original data set. So basically I would like to remove all the data points that are increasing or decreasing in linear fashion  (This might remove data in original df also that has linear relation)

Comment: Maybe you can add a column calculating the difference, and afterwards search the areas where the difference is linear (`| [i] - [i-1] | < 0.03` or something similar) and substitute those values with `np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

I can raise you something like this:

```
for i in xrange(df.__len__()):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    df.loc[i, ('lin_one')] = df.loc[i, ('one')] - df.loc[i - 1, ('one')]
    df.loc[i, ('lin_two')] = df.loc[i, ('two')] - df.loc[i - 1, ('two')]

for i in xrange(df.__len__()-1):
    if df.lin_one[i] - df.lin_one[i+1] != 0 and df.lin_one[i] - df.lin_one[i+1] < 0.003:
        df.loc[i,('one')] = np.nan
    if df.lin_two[i] - df.lin_two[i+1] != 0 and df.lin_two[i] - df.lin_two[i+1] < 0.003:
        df.loc[i,('two')] = np.nan
```

This will produce the following output:

```
                  index        one   lin_one        two  lin_two
0   2017:10:03 03:44:00  13.615049  0.000000  14.650001    0.000
1   2017:10:03 03:45:00  13.615049  0.000000  14.650001    0.000
2   2017:10:03 03:46:00  13.615049  0.000000        NaN    0.000
3   2017:10:03 03:47:00  13.615049  0.000000        NaN    0.025
4   2017:10:03 03:48:00        NaN -0.015049        NaN    0.025
5   2017:10:03 03:49:00        NaN  0.102089        NaN    0.025
6   2017:10:03 03:50:00        NaN  0.102089        NaN    0.025
7   2017:10:03 03:51:00        NaN  0.102089        NaN    0.025
8   2017:10:03 03:52:00        NaN  0.102089  14.800000    0.025
9   2017:10:03 03:53:00        NaN  0.102089  14.800000    0.000
10  2017:10:03 03:54:00  14.212537  0.102089  14.800000    0.000
11  2017:10:03 03:55:00  14.242533  0.029996  14.800000    0.000
```

then you can delete the calculating columns `lin_one` and `lin_two`:

```
del df['lin_one']
del df['lin_two']
```

But this method kills one value of the not interpolated data...

Comment: Its working on small sample but if i apply on whole data Its not accurate. and any reason why to use 0.03 ?

Comment: I only had the sample data provided above. No specific reason to use `0.03`, was just a start value which can be adjusted to your needs. You can adjust it based on the output.